# C# remove line using regular expression, including line break

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove lines that match a particular pattern from some text. One way to do this is to use a regular expression with the begin/end anchors, like so:

```
var re = new Regex("^pattern$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string final = re.Replace(initial, "");
```

This works fine except that it leaves an empty line instead of removing the entire line (including the line break).

To solve this, I added an optional capturing group for the line break, but I want to be sure it includes all of the different flavors of line breaks, so I did it like so:

```
var re = new Regex(@"^pattern$(\r\n|\r|\n)?", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string final = re.Replace(initial, "");
```

This works, but it seems like there should be a more straightforward way to do this. Is there a simpler way to reliably remove the entire line including the ending line break (if any)?

Comment: Well, `@"^pattern$[\s-[\p{Zs}\t]]*"` will do what you need. Make sure the CR is matched, probably ``@"^pattern\r?$[\s-[\p{Zs}\t]]*"`` will do better.

Answer (score 3):

To match any single line break sequence you may use `(?:\r\n|[\r\n\u000B\u000C\u0085\u2028\u2029])` pattern. So, instead of `(\r\n|\r|\n)?`, you can use `(?:\r\n|[\r\n\u000B\u000C\u0085\u2028\u2029])?`.

Details:

- `‎000A` - a newline, `\n`
- `‎000B` - a line tabulation char
- `‎000C` - a form feed char
- `‎000D` - a carriage return, `\r`
- `‎0085` - a next line char, `NEL`
- `‎2028` - a line separator char
  ‎- `2029` - a paragraph separator char.

If you want to remove any 0+ non-horizontal (or vertical) whitespace chars after a matched line, you may use `[\s-[\p{Zs}\t]]*`: any whitespace (`\s`) but (`-[...]`) a horizontal whitespace (matched with `[\p{Zs}\t]`). Note that for some reason, `\p{Zs}` Unicode category class does not match tab chars.

One more aspect must be dealt with here since you are using the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option: it makes `$` match before a newline (`\n`) or end of string. That is why if your line endings are CRLF the pattern may fail to match. Hence, add an optional `\r?` before `$` in your pattern.

So, either use

```
@"^pattern\r?$(?:\r\n|[\r\n\u000B\u000C\u0085\u2028\u2029])?"
```

or

```
@"^pattern\r?$[\s-[\p{Zs}\t]]*"
```

Comment: Definitely not a simpler solution, but kudos on going all-in on the reliability front. One thing you mentioned, prompted me to double-check the documentation and then do some testing. It turns out that the `$` anchor only matches `\n`. So `\r` does not count as a line break, and the `\r` is always removed when removing a line delineated by `^...$`. I also spot-checked some of your other proposed line ending characters and none were matched by `$`. So for my original question it seems that simply removing `\n` is enough.

Comment: @JackA. Just to correct one important bit:`$` matches a *location* right before `\n` when `Multiline` option is provided. `\r` - if there - must be consumed with the `pattern`. You did not explain what the pattern is, maybe it ends with `.*`, then you really do not need any `\r?`. My answer is a generic one for a *matching any line break sequence or any line break symbols (veritcal whitespace)* question that I assumed yours is.